# OverRiding Vs PolyMorphism

Tags: polymorphism, overriding

What is the difference between the two?

A super class having `myMethod(int a)`  and an inheriting class having the same method,
Is this overriding or polymorphism?

I am clear with the difference b/w overriding and overloading, but the polymorphism and overriding seems the same. Or are they?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Overriding is when you call a method on an object and the method in the subclass with the same signature as the one in the superclass is called.

Polymorphism is where you are not sure of the objects type at runtime and the most specific method is called. Therefore the behaviour of the method called may differ, depending on the objects type at runtime.

Overriding is a type of polymorphism along with overloading and dynamic (late) binding. You can see more details [here about the different types.](https://web.archive.org/web/20110923215626/http://home.cogeco.ca:80/%7Eve3ll/jatutor5.htm)

Comment: it means the difference is just that, in overriding, i know what method would be called, but if multiple children are inheriting from the same class, and i dont know what type of child will be called, it is polymorphism..So basically, polymorphism is a concept the makes use of Overriding?
Am i getting it correct?

Comment: Yes almost. Overriding is a way to achieve polymorphism and polymorphism is the result of this overriding. Polymorphism is just a principle that can be achieved by overriding, overloading and dynamic (late) binding.

Comment: Link is dead/404.

Answer (score 2):

I am doing my software architecture exam tomorrow, and this is what i have understood from my reading.

Polymorphism is a concept of object oriented programming that allows a field, in this case, an object, to be changed from one form to another. Poly = multiple, morph = change.

Overriding a method, is essentially a dynamic binding of a method which allows a method to be changed during run-time. It is a form of polymorphism since a method's functionality gets changed over the course of time.

I took some of my facts from here - 
https://beginnersbook.com/2013/03/polymorphism-in-java/

Comment: Somehow, I am hesitant to believe this answer just because of your username :P.

Answer (score 1):

yes...by using overriding we achieve the property of polymorphism  ...when u have multiple
class deriving from a single parent class ...there by using overriding ...we define the derived  class method's functionality and as they are derived from same parent we show the  property of polymorphism..

Comment: nicely, succinctly said.