# Is overriding Concept of polymorphism or Concept of inheritance? OOP

Tags: oop, inheritance, polymorphism, overriding

I had an interview today, I was asked this question and I answered that overriding is the concept of Inheritance but They kept saying that No, its the concept of Polymorphism!
I was pretty sure. But now I think I'll need some more exposure.

There could be long answers! but in single word what will  it be "Inheritance" or "Polymorphism"

Comment: What is your definition of inheritance?

Comment: Short answer: Polymorphism

Long answer:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7489335/overriding-vs-polymorphism

Comment: Inheritance is when a class is based on another class,  "IS A" relation between parent child hierarchy.

Comment: @Link but for heterogeneous implementation, you do polymorphism by Inheritance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what they were asking you to expound upon were the "4 properties of an Object Oriented Programming Language."  Although these classical attributes seem to be weathered and time-worn, I would say that they remain apt to object-oriented paradigms.

These 4 properties are:

- Inheritance (object hierarchies for "is a" relations)
- Abstraction (function over implementation details)
- Encapsulation (information hiding)
- Polymorphism (which requires overriding)

Overriding is closer to polymorphism than to inheritance since it is possible to subclass without overriding any methods.  However, polymorphism always requires that a subclass override some superclass method.

Comment: I said that overriding could be in both inheritance and polymorphism, but they replied overriding is only for polymorphism.

Comment: While the statement "overriding is only for polymorphism" may not be strictly correct, they're the ones that are judging the answers to their own interview questions.  Since overriding is necessary for polymorphism, it probably would have been safer to emphasize that point to them.

Comment: but for heterogeneous implementation, you do polymorphism by Inheritance?

Comment: "polymorphism always requires that a subclass override some superclass method" should be -> "**run-time** polymorphism always requires that a subclass override some superclass method".

Answer (score 0):

I would say both. We use override in inheritance to override a function behaviour of base class function. This is also called called runtime polymorphism as wheather to call base class function or derived is decided at runtime. But yes, i agree with scottb, they would be expecting which pillar of OOPS is strongly connected to Override.

Answer (score 0):

Polymorphism : overloading

Inheritance : overriding

Even though both the concepts overlap in meaning and definition.

Polymorphism = one method multiple definitions = overloading.

Inheritance = extend base class or change its existing behavior = overriding.  (not exactly though)

While both overriding & overloading achieve polymorphism, thinking about overriding without inheritance is almost meaningless. (Why would I ever need to override in the same class even if it were possible? I may instead overload if I need multiple definations.)

Comment: I disagree.  Overloading is neither necessary nor sufficient for polymorphism.  Conversely, polymorphism cannot be accomplished without overriding.

Comment: Polymorphism = one method multiple definations = overloading.

Comment: Inheritance = extend base class or change its existing behavior = overriding.  (not exactly though)

Comment: No no this is more messed up then my own question :P :D

Comment: In many languages, Java in particular, there is a sharp distinction between overloading and overriding.  In Java, overloading is a compile-time phenomenon based on method or constructor signatures, whereas overriding is a run-time phenomenon in which the JVM dynamically dispatches execution based on the object type on which a method invocation occurs.  In the case of Java, at least, overloading is an inadequate mechanism for achieving the OOP goal of polymorphism.

Comment: OOP is a concept. Language implementation is an entirely different thing altogether. But when given the choice to go this side or that side only, I think what I answered is the closest. Though just as I said you can't equate them 1 on 1. Polymorphism includes overriding too and you can obviously overload in inherited class.

Comment: *" I think what I answered is the closest. "* ... Well, ok ... but let the record show that I have provided a concrete example in which your understanding of *overriding and overloading* is neither precise nor accurate.

Comment: While both overriding & overloading achieve polymorphism, thinking about overriding without inheritance is almost meaningless. (Why would I ever need to override in the same class even if it were possible? I may instead overload if I need multiple definations.) So you see the analogy for my answer now?